# GStreamer pipeline stiring from pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

is there a way how to get a pipeline string from the pipeline? I am looking for something like opposite of the gst_parse_launch function which would take the pipeline as parameter and returned the string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. The closest I can think of is to generate a pipeline diagram in the dot format. To do so, you can place [gst_debug_bin_to_dot_file](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/debugutils.html?gi-language=c#gst_debug_bin_to_dot_file) at the point in your code when you want to render the pipeline graph (likely when it's already playing). Then execute you app with the GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR variable. Something like:

```
GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=. ./app
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I knew about his possibility but was curious if there is way to get the string. I suppose it's not possible.